# Is there a better way to use the new Facebook Comments plug-in in iOS apps?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-comments

I saw this solution:
http://suhinini.me/2011/05/24/embedding-facebook-social-comments-plugin-to-an-ios-application/

but is there any other solution?

that using the FB SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any so had to create my own :) I personally wait for Facebook to provide their own SDK solution but, AFAIU, there isn't any.